How can I configure Git to download files at clone but ignore local changes for all users?
I'm using GitHub with admin privileges on the repo.
I have files on the remote repository that I need collaborators to have (so they remain on the remote and are downloaded during a clone). However, I want these files to be ignored for local changes — meaning when collaborators modify or delete them, the changes are not tracked or prompted for commit.
This also includes a directory where any new files added locally (by a process or user) should not even be suggested for git add.
Is there a way to configure this behavior directly on the GitHub server?
What I tried (or considered):
Gitignore. I don’t think I should add the files or directory to .gitignore, because my understanding is that this would prevent them from being included in the repository when cloned. Is that correct? Can I instead add them to .gitignore on the remote in a way that ensures they get cloned but are not tracked for changes?
Chat-GPT told me about Repository-Wide Exclude, but then explained it was a local solution and is not pushed to remote, so collaborators would not automatically have the same exclusions after a clone.
The files are data files, and we want the same starting point for the data files, and we want dev-users to be able to change without the clutter of tracked files you don't really want to track.
Specifics: It is an ArcGIS Pro dataset, including a map file of extension .aprx and multiple binaries in a database directory (gdb, proprietary to ESRI.
The app, ArcGIS Pro, makes changes to the file when you zoom the view or turn off a layer. Other dev operations sometimes change files inside the gdb directory. These are all part of the development process.

Are these config files, and you want a default file but not any local changes?

@JimRedmond , They are data files, and we want the same starting point for the data files, and we want dev-users to be able to change without the clutter of tracked files you don't really want to track. Specifics: It is an ArcGIS Pro dataset, including a map file of extension .aprx and multiple binaries in a database directory (gdb, proprietary to ESRI.

Put the sideband data files in a separate branch (and hence in their own directory), add a worktree for that branch, then the non-sideband and sideband histories are separate.
